# Python: How to print an ndarray in scientific notation (rounded) as part of a print statement

Tags: python, printing, numpy-ndarray, scientific-notation

I have an ndarray that I want to print in scientific notation with rounding as part of a sentence, this is what I currently have

```
data_arr = np.array([12345, 12345])
print('This is the data ', *data_arr)
```

and the output is

```
This is the data  12345 12345
```

Is there a way to print in scientific notation, with rounding, preferably in one line, like below?

```
This is the data  1.2e+04 1.2e+04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String formating seems to be the way to go. Example:

```
data_arr = np.array([12345, 12345])
print('This is the data {:.1e} {:.1e}'.format(*data_arr))
```

prints what you're looking for. To adjust the number of figures after the dot to, for example, three, just change `1e` to `3e`.